# process credit cards without using a gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, payment-processing

Is it possible to take online payments without using a payment gateway or a third party checkout like google checkout, and how? The point is to avoid the fees of payment gateways.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the payment gateways also provide much needed security and fraud-protection for ecommerce... We rely on them to check the authenticity of payments and they help get us in touch with the banks directly to match details.

I think they are necessary if you are running an online business at all.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your able to handle authentication in real time I'd say no. Also, companies that do, have very strict PCI rules that are rarely worth the hassle. Let them do the heavy lifting so you can focus on what your site does best.